# ionic 5 project shows blank template after cloning from git

Tags: angular, git, ionic-framework, node-modules, npm-install

I've cloned my ionic angular-based project containing some plugins, but it seems that the plugins doesn't work .when i type

```
ionic serve -l
```

it shows me a blank project.
I've tried

```
npm install
```

after cloning from git, also started the cloned project with

```
ionic start <name> <template>
```

based on [this doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/start), but none of them helped me. fyi the version of ionic is 5.4.16 and npm is 6.13.4.

Comment: on which ionic version your project were built?

Comment: on ionic version 6.1.0 @NajamUsSaqib